# The sortReplies() function is not working using Rivescript

Tags: javascript, rivescript

I am using Rivescript to build a simple chatbot
but when I run the file, the chatbots replies with an error

> ERR: Replies Not Sorted.

```
function botReady() {
    bot.sortReplies();
    botReply('Hello');
}
```